# Why when add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> to web page don´t work on hosting?

Tags: php, xhtml, hosting, wsod

I am developing a simple webpage at hostgator.com.
I have the standard headers, but when I add the following line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

the page does not work. I would like why.

This is the full header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es" xml:lang="es"> 
... rest of code ...
```

The server returns me a blank page

---

***Issue solved:*** The PHP short tags was open.

Answer (score 8):

My best guess is that:

- The document is being processed as PHP
- [Short Tags are turned on](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

… so the server is trying to process the XML declaration as PHP code. Normally I'd expect an error message, but perhaps there is a PHP setting in play that suppresses errors to the client to avoid leaking data that could be potentially useful to someone trying a security exploit.

Just remove it.

- UTF-8 is the default
- version 1.0 is the default
- It is optional in the spec
- Given a text/html content-type, an XML prolog will trigger IE6's quirks mode

The latter is undesirable. The former all mean it makes no difference.

Answer (score -1):

```php
<?php
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
?>
```