# Unexpected T_STRING error on server but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, parsing

So on my localhost my website is running fine, but when i run it on a server on my workplace (it has PHP 5.3.3) i keep getting the unexpected T_STRING error. 
I have pinpointed the problem down to a function: exportXML (when i remove this function the website is working)

Any ideas?
I'm kinda sure that my code is correct..

```
Error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /opt/www-abba/paintingtool/index.php on line 427
```

FYI Line 427 is this one:
            window.open("data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,"+XML);

Code (yes this is JavaScript in a .php file):

```
function exportXML(){
            var keys = Object.keys(jSelectedStation);
            //Trim all values
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
                if(jSelectedStation[keys[i]] !=null)
                {
                    jSelectedStation[keys[i]] = jSelectedStation[keys[i]].trim();
                }
                else
                {
                    jSelectedStation[keys[i]] = "";
                }
            }

            //STATION XML
            XML="<station stationNr='"+jSelectedStation.STATNAM+"'><definitionstat><admtyp>"+jSelectedStation.ADMTYP+"</admtyp><responsible>"+jSelectedStation.RESPONSIBLE+"</responsible><bildnam>"+jSelectedStation.BILDNAM+"</bildnam><stattyp>"+jSelectedStation.STATTYP+"</stattyp><stattel>"+jSelectedStation.STATTEL+"</stattel><statnr>"+jSelectedStation.STATNR+"</statnr><zonenr>"+jSelectedStation.ZONENR+"</zonenr><stattext>"+jSelectedStation.STATTEXT+"</stattext><xcoordinate>"+jSelectedStation.XCOORDINATE+"</xcoordinate><ycoordinate>"+jSelectedStation.YCOORDINATE+"</ycoordinate><refresh>"+jSelectedStation.REFRESH+"</refresh><groupid>"+jSelectedStation.GROUPID+"</groupid><position>"+jSelectedStation.POSITION+"</position><extra1>"+jSelectedStation.EXTRA1+"+</extra1><extra2>"+jSelectedStation.EXTRA2+"</extra2><extra3>"+jSelectedStation.EXTRA3+"</extra3><quittype>"+jSelectedStation.QUITTYPE+"</quittype><aliaslist><alias type='imelda'>"+jSelectedStation.IMELDA+"</alias></aliaslist><statcfg>"+jSelectedStation.STATCFG+"</statcfg></definitionstat><logic></logic><logicf></logicf><devices>";

            var keys = Object.keys(racks);
            for (var i = 1; i < keys.length; i++) //For all elements in Racks, print XML line
            { //1 to skip EMPTY
                dev = racks[keys[i]];
                if(dev.punkt[0] != undefined)
                {
                    currKrt=dev.punkt[0].y;
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log(dev);
                }
                XML+="<device statdev='"+keys[i]+"'><definitiondev><dvtyp>"+dev.type+"</dvtyp><bildnam>"+dev.bildnam+"</bildnam><responsible>"+dev.responsible+"</responsible><text>"+dev.text+"</text>";
                    if(dev.type == "I" || dev.type == "A")
                    {
                        XML+="<i_plaus_min>"+dev.extraProp[0]+"</i_plaus_min><i_plaus_max>"+dev.extraProp[1]+"</i_plaus_max><i_ala_min>"+dev.extraProp[2]+"</i_ala_min><i_ala_max>"+dev.extraProp[3]+"</i_ala_max><i_reference>"+dev.extraProp[4]+"</i_reference>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        XML+="<i_plaus_min>0</i_plaus_min><i_plaus_max>0</i_plaus_max><i_ala_min>0</i_ala_min><i_ala_max>0</i_ala_max><i_reference>0</i_reference>";
                    }
                XML+="<record>"+dev.record+"</record><extratext></extratext><quittype>M</quittype><punkt><kaartdev plaats='"+currKrt.substring(0,currKrt.indexOf(" "))+"'>";
                devpkt = 1;
                    for (var x=0; x < dev.punkt.length; x++)
                    {
                    if(dev.punkt[x] != undefined)
                        {
                        if(dev.punkt[x].y != currKrt)
                        {
                            currKrt = dev.punkt[x].y;
                            XML+="</kaartdev><kaartdev plaats='"+currKrt.substring(0,currKrt.indexOf(" "))+"'>";
                        }
                        //console.log("["+dev.punkt[x].y.substring(dev.punkt[x].y.indexOf(" ")+1,dev.punkt[x].y.length)+"]");
                        XML+="<devpkt id='"+devpkt+"'><pkttyp>"+dev.punkt[x].y.substring(dev.punkt[x].y.indexOf(" ")+1,dev.punkt[x].y.length)+"</pkttyp><pktcons>100</pktcons><bitnrk>"+dev.punkt[x].x+"</bitnrk><bitstatus>0</bitstatus></devpkt>";
                        devpkt++;
                        // if(devpkt>16){alert("More then 16 pkts, THIS IS MADNESS");throw "Stopping execution because not all punkts are defined";}
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            alert("Not all punkt for " + keys[i] + " are defined. \nPlease define punkt " + (x+1));
                            throw "Stopping execution because not all punkts are defined";
                        }
                    }
                XML+="</kaartdev></punkt></definitiondev><refdev refnam='";
                // Refdev substring
                if(dev.refdev.indexOf("-") > -1)
                {
                    XML += dev.refdev.substring(0,dev.refdev.indexOf("-")) + "'/></device>";
                }
                else
                {
                    XML += dev.refdev+"'/></device>";
                }
            }
            XML += "</devices><iodef></iodef></station>";
            window.open("data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"+XML);
            // window.open("data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"+XML.innerHTML,"ABBA XML","width=800,height=600");
            }
```

Comment: You have [short tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) turned on in php.ini on the server?

Comment: @bagonyi can you explain 'short tags'?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: Duplicate [PHP Parse error - unexpected T_STRING [duplicate]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506057/php-parse-error-unexpected-t-string)

Comment: And duplicate of [Why when add <?xml version=“1.0” encoding=“utf-8”?> to web page don´t work on hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361750/why-when-add-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8-to-web-page-dont-work-on-ho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have `short_open_tag = On` on server, so `<?xml` is parsed as php code start.

Set `short_open_tag = Off` via php.ini or .htaccess.

Comment: Great stuff! fixed it !

Comment: +1 for nice catch.I would prefer using `echo` to output the line instead of `short_open_tag = Off` as changing the `short_open_tag` is not easy on some hosted/shared servers.

Comment: @bansi good idea :) I was indeed waiting for my Server Admin to make the change.

Comment: @bansi tested it and             <?php echo "window.open(\"data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\"+XML);" ?> does not do the trick :/

Comment: hmmm your syntax is correct. have you removed/echo the comment on the next line? there also you have `<?`

Answer (score 1):

This is the line causing the error:

```
window.open("data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
                                         ^                                    ^
```

If you have [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) configuration enabled (check your [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo) output to see), then PHP will try parse everything inside `<?` and `?>` as PHP code. In this case, `<?xml` is being considered as the starting of a PHP code block, and that's what generates the error.

Comment: Great stuff! fixed it !

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced the same issue. It was due to `short_open_tag` on. Try this in `.htaccess`. It worked for me

`php_value short_open_tag 0`